# How do you unlink a symlink created with Microsoft's linkd.exe tool?

Tags: symlink

I'm using Microsoft linkd.exe tool to create symlinks, but then I typed linkd -d and it created a link called "-d"

now I cant remove "-d"

LOL this sucks.

So i renamed it to ddd so it wouldnt think it was an option.

But I still need to know how to unlink things =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no actually you have to use the linkd.exe tool still. del {linkfile} remove all the content at the source =/ oops!

linkd /d

Comment: Big oops! I'm going to delete my answer. You might want to rewrite your answer to directly say `del linkfile` will do that, instead of referring to my soon-to-be-missing one.

Answer (score 2):

This makes it appear that the contents of the `bar` directory is inside the `foo` directory:

```
linkd foo bar
```

And this breaks the link:

```
linkd foo /D
```

You have to be careful, as some actions delete the contents of bar instead of breaking the link. For example, don't delete things.